# Show every date even it doesn't has value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to fetch all data by all dates per month.

I have this table. I have a problem when I create it at sqlfiddle.

```
CREATE TABLE Outlet
(
    IdOutlet [int] NOT NULL,
    OutletCode [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    Description [varchar](225) NULL
);
```

Outlet record(s)

```
1 | K-AEON   | Desc1
2 | K-LFTEJM | Desc2
```

and this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesOrderHeader]
(
    [TransactionNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [TransDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ETADate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ExternalDocument] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Reference] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [RefTransNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerCode] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Remark] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Remark2] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [TermOfPayment] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Currency] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Rate] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [UseVAT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubTotal] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [DiscPercent] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [DiscAmount] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [GrandTotal] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [TotalReceivable] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [FromCustomerCode] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [PostingStatus] [int] NULL,
    [PostingBy] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [PostingDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerReceivable] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [LocationCode] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [VatPercent] [float] NOT NULL,
    [VatAmount] [float] NULL,
    [FinalReleasedDate_Outlet] [datetime] NULL,
    [CancelStatus] [int] NULL,
    [CancelReason] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CancelledBy] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__SalesOrd__554342D81FCDBCEB] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TransactionNo] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
                ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As you can see I have two tables. For now I have this query to fetch all my data.

```
select 
    CustomerCode, CONVERT(date, transdate) tanggal,
    SUM(totalreceivable) total 
from 
    SalesOrderHeader 
where 
    TransDate between '$start_date' and '$end_date'
group by 
    CONVERT(date, transdate), CustomerCode
```

Here is an example result

```
K-AEON      2016-07-18  2841600.00000000000000000000
K-LFTEJM    2016-07-17  4862190.00000000000000000000
```

But I want this result

```
            |1 | 2 | 3 |  4-16  |      17      |   18      | 19-29 |30|
   K-AEON   |..|   |   | ...... |    2841600   |           | ..... |..|
  K-LFTEJM  |..|   |   |        |              |  4862190  |       |..|
```

How can I achieve that? What method can I use?

I want to put it on `sqlfiddle` but I got this result `Create script error`

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selected date;

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (OutletCode VARCHAR(50), Date_ DATETIME, TotalAmount DECIMAL(38, 20))

DECLARE @SelectedDate DATETIME = '2016.07.01'
DECLARE @CountOfDay INT = 1
DECLARE @DayCountForSelectedMonth INT = DATEDIFF(day, @SelectedDate, dateadd(month, 1, @SelectedDate))
DECLARE @Days NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('K-AEON', '2016-07-18', 2841600.00000000000000000000)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('K-LFTEJM', '2016-07-17' ,4862190.00000000000000000000)


;WITH CountOfDayTable(CountOfDay)
AS
(
    SELECT @CountOfDay
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CountOfDay + 1
    FROM CountOfDayTable
    WHERE CountOfDay < @DayCountForSelectedMonth
)

SELECT 
     @Days = COALESCE(@Days + ', ','') + '[' + CAST(CountOfDay AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ']'
FROM CountOfDayTable C
-- SELECT @Days -- [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]

SET @Query = 

    'SELECT * FROM (SELECT day(Date_) DayOfTrans, * FROM #Test) T
    PIVOT(Max(TotalAmount) FOR DayOfTrans IN  -- OR MIN
            (' +
                    @Days
               +    
            ')
        ) FinalRes';

-- SELECT @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering your example result,

```
    DECLARE @T AS TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(50), TransDate DATETIME, TotalReceivable DECIMAL(38, 20))

    INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('K-AEON', '2016-07-18', 2841600.00000000000000000000)
    INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('K-LFTEJM', '2016-07-17' ,4862190.00000000000000000000)

    SELECT * FROM (SELECT day(Transdate) DayOfTrans,*FROM @T) T
    PIVOT(Max(TotalReceivable) FOR DayOfTrans 
     IN ([1], [2], [3], [17], [18], [19], [20])) FinalRes
```

The desired output is,

```
Name        TransDate               1       2       3       17      18      19      20
--------    ----------------------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- 
K-LFTEJM    2016-07-17 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL  4862190.00000000000000000000 NULL  NULL  NULL
K-AEON      2016-07-18 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL  NULL  2841600.00000000000000000000 NULL  NULL
```

Comment: it is almost like what i want. How to make the `[1] [2] [3]` to all date in a month

Comment: @YVS1102: Thanks. You might have to write a dynamic query in order to get the [1], [2]s for the given Month. Or you may keep columns from [1] to [31] and manage it at your front-end.

Comment: if i write it `static` some month has [30] and [29]

Comment: If this can't be handled at the later stages, I would suggest you to go with the Dynamic SQL.